# Select the next <td> in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3 application. I am building table dynamically with a data from database. I have a certain case when the third column/cell from a row is a dropdown :

```
<select name="YesNoNotApplicable" class="YesNoNotApplicable">
                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                            <option value="2">No</option>
                            <option value="3">Not Applicable</option>
                        </select>
```

In this case the fourth column/cell stays empty and if the user select 3(Not Applicable) in the fourth cell should be shown a textbox where the user can write additional information. I have poor knowledge in JS and jQuery, however I find out how to get the selected value from a dropdown :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.YesNoNotApplicable').change(function () {
            alert($('.YesNoNotApplicable').val());
        });
    });
```

But now instead the alert I need to check if the value is 3(this is the far I can go by myself) and to show/hide or append/remove a textbox from the next cell or  if we talk in a DOM prespective.

So how can I navigate to the  next to the one with class=YesNoNotApplicable and what is the best way to deal with this text box - to put it in the  while I'm creating the table and then to show/hide it or to deal with it during run time and append/remove it and how could I do that?

Comment: Use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you are using strongly typed model and html helpers for your view, it would probably better to create input element while creating the table. The reason is the elements you would create via jQuery won't be bound to your model.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.YesNoNotApplicable').change(function () {
       if($(this).val() === "3")
         $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').show();
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes I do use strongly-typed model and I need this to be bound to my model. You suggestion guarantee that, right?

Comment: Yes, if you use @Html.TextBoxFor() extension method for input. It will be bound to your model.

Answer (score 12):

Within the `change` callback, `this` will refer to the `select` element. So you can find the `td` containing it with [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), and then the next `td` via [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) (since you *know* the next thing is a `td`, this is a table), like this:

```
var $nextTD = $(this).closest('td').next();
```

In the more general case where you want to do something similar but not in a table, and the sibling you want to find may be more than one element away, you might use `nextAll("selector").first()`. But if the thing you want is the next element, and you're sure of that, you don't need [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll).

Comment: +1. Ha, managed to provide a well structured answer in the time it took me to add a comment... well done sir

Comment: Thanks, a lot of useful info.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.YesNoNotApplicable').change(function () {
       if($(this).val() === "3"){
         $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input:text').show();
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var nextCell = $(this).closest('td').next();`

And you can then work with the next cel.

Comment: It's best to delete answers when you see you're just duplicating an earlier one.

Comment: I didn't see it I was just in my phone and typed much slower than the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `siblings()` method to get next `td` tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.YesNoNotApplicable').change(function () {
            if($('.YesNoNotApplicable').val() == '3'){
               $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.YesNoNotApplicable').change(function () {
            if($('.YesNoNotApplicable').val() == '3'){
               $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
#notapplicable{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><select name="YesNoNotApplicable" class="YesNoNotApplicable">
                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                            <option value="2">No</option>
                            <option value="3">Not Applicable</option>
                        </select></td>
     <td><input type='text' id='notapplicable' /></td>
  </tr>
  
  
</table>
```